# Deploy app in Visual Studio 2013 error

Tags: app, visual-studio-2013

When i try to deploy my app in Visual Studio 2013 i get this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': We're
>   sorry, we weren't able to complete the operation, please try again in
>   a few minutes. If you see this message repeatedly, contact your
>   administrator.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is the type of your app (SharePoint-hosted or Provider-hosted) and where do you want to deploy it.

Comment: it is SharePoint-hosted

Comment: Have you configured App environment properly? following link might help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515677/MyplusFirstplusSharepoint-HostedplusAppplusinplus

Comment: If you want to deploy it on your local farm, you must configure your environment, you can refer to this link : [http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/02/13/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-aspx/](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/02/13/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-aspx).
You can also deploy it on your Office 365 environment, in that case, you only need a developer site in order to test your app directly in your site.

Comment: Why do i have to make such complicated configuration just to deploy a custom ribbon?

Comment: You can deploy your custom ribbon by using a sharepoint solution and not an app, specifically when you're doing that on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you will need to set up your development environment properly:

[How to: Set up an on-premises development environment for apps for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/fp179923.aspx)

For your custom Ribbon, please have a look here:

[SharePoint 2013: Create Ribbon custom action | SharePoint-Journey.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuuRib9Krpo)